# prolog passing a function as a variable, how to add arguments?

Tags: prolog, declarative

I have this arbitrary function that I need to call many times with different variables.
btw, this is SWI-Prolog

```
perform(V1,V2,V3,Function,Result):-
    % 
    % do little stuf.
    %
    Function(Arg1,Arg2,Result).
```

This gives a syntax error.

But passing a function as a variable without adding arguments works fine as in the following code:

```
perform(Function):-
    Function.

sayHello:-
    write('hello').

:-perform(sayHello).
```

So how to add arguments to a variable function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specifically in SWI-Prolog you can use `call` . Quoting the manual:

> call(:Goal, +ExtraArg1, ...)
>
> Append ExtraArg1, ExtraArg2, ... to the
>   argument list of Goal and call the result. For example, call(plus(1),
>   2, X) will call plus(1, 2, X), binding X to 3. The call/[2..]
>   construct is handled by the compiler. The predicates call/[2-8] are
>   defined as real (meta-)predicates and are available to inspection
>   through current_predicate/1, predicate_property/2, etc. Higher
>   arities are handled by the compiler and runtime system, but the
>   predicates are not accessible for inspection.

where the plus indicates that the `argument must be fully instantiated to a term that satisfies the required argument type`, and the colon indicates that the `agument is a meta-argument` (this also implies "+").

Comment: The `:` and `+` arguments specification begs explaining to the novice. :)

Comment: call/n is now part of the standard if I'm not mistaken, so it's not specific to SWI-Prolog

Comment: 1) meta-argument is something like a predicate, a goal or a clause passed as an argument; 2) I am not sure about the standard but indeed SWI is not the only to implement call/N, SICStus has it as well (starting from version 4), I am not sure about other dialects...

Comment: The modes in SWI are often different to the ISO modes. I cannot see the point why `call(:Goal, +ExtraArg1)` should have a plus at all. [In ISO, it is rather a ?](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#call). Think of `?- call(=(1), X)`.